# Beliefs of polemical people

Tags: cognitive-psychology, personality

Are there studies on the beliefs of polemical people?

Has anyone tried to classify the most common beliefs behind the automatic thoughts of polemical people?

Comment: Have you tried [Googling "beliefs polemic psychology"](https://www.google.com/search?q=beliefs+polemic+psychology) for yourself yet? A number of potentially useful results emerge immediately. Your question would become clearer if you could explain what you're looking for, if it can't be found this easily. [This New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0) might be a good place to start as well.

Comment: I will try to read the article. However I'm wondering if the psychology has tried to find the correlation between the result of the different tests and tools. Beliefs, MMPI, SCID, MBTI.. how do they bind together? I know the answer would be huge, but I'm more interested in only some kind of people.. i.e. some people would like to fight for their ideas, some of these are also polemica, at the opposit some others people are really adaptive to serve their boss.. have this people a common characterization? Why this difference of values?

Comment: I don't think it's quite right to think of polemicism as the opposite of adaptive subservience. Polemical people don't only fight when it's maladaptive or when their opponent is superior in authority or social status. Maybe polemical isn't the word you really want. Could you try using other words to describe what you mean by "polemical"? BTW, you'd probably be better off just forgetting about the MBTI...As a personality psychologist, I have a very low opinion of it. It may not be completely invalid, but it will probably confuse and mislead you more than it will really help describe personality

Comment: I don't want to mislead you into thinking the only way to approach your question is from a clinical perspective, because polemicism certainly isn't simply pathological or categorical...but you might be interested in exploring theory related to a childhood disorder, [*oppositional defiant disorder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppositional_defiant_disorder): `An ongoing pattern of anger-guided disobedience, hostility, and defiant behavior toward authority figures that goes beyond the bounds of normal childhood behavior.`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will read that article and in the next days I will try to write a better question